# Subscription to a Collection doesn't work in meteor

Tags: meteor

```
//in Client
console.log("------------------------------------------------);
Meteor.subscribe('completed', query, function(){
    jobs_completed = new Meteor.Collection("GE_qstat_jobs_completed");
    console.log("inside subscribe");
    displayTable(jobs_completed);
});
console.log("------------------------------------------------);
//in Server
Meteor.publish("completed", function(query){
    console.log("   completed -> Done");
    return jobs_completed.find(query, {fields: {ClusterId: 0}});
});
```

the `Meteor.subscribe` seems like is not working because when I execute the app I got the two lines and I don't get the message inside the function, so the one million dollars questions is, what the heck am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, this is the correct way to do it, in my case I'm working with more than 12,500 record and it took more than 15 minutes to show what I was expecting to see, so I thought something was wrong